# How to trigger/run/execute scheduled task manually?

Tags: rules

Is there a way to run a scheduled task manually without any programming?

If not, this way seems not to work properly [Manual execution of scheduled rule](https://www.drupal.org/node/2260529). 
After executing a rule, having another one on the list, clearing caches and running the cron, this feature automatically disappears somehow. There is something wrong in the code.

Comment: Do you want to do it with Rules? If so, when you created a component and scheduled it with rules scheduler, under the Rules Components Tab there will be links next to the listed component, in particular 'execute' whereby you may execute the component, and schedule, which allows manual scheduling of the component. This is mainly there to help debugging the rule component saving you from the trouble of advancing your hosting machines clock.

Comment: @J. Reynolds I would like to execute a scheduled rule earlier than a scheduled date. There is only 'delete' in the scheduled tab. I tried to execute the component but it seems that it's not possible to execute the specific scheduled component?

Comment: Exactly, but it seems you might not have Rules Scheduler installed. It is a sub module of Rules. When it is installed you can schedule Rules to execute at specific times via a Cron run. And you are definitely looking in the wrong tab. You need to be on the Rules Component Tab.

Comment: @J. Reynolds I suppose that this sub module has been already installed by default. I looked in the Rules Component Tab. Yes, there is a function 'execute' but it seems that it is not possible to execute the specific scheduled rule/component which is already in the Rules Schedule Tab. Is that right? For example, a transmission of userpoints has been already scheduled and I would like to execute it a little bit earlier than the scheduled date.

Comment: @J. Reynolds I have verified better and it can be concluded that there is no Rules ID in the Component executing rule set, if I am not wrong, so there is no out of box solution?

Comment: I hesitate to post this as an actual answer (I might convert my comment later on if it makes sense) ... but a possible alternative could be to just use the "execute link" for the actual rules component itself (which is executed right away). And then combine that with a "delete" of what is shown in the scheduled Rules components.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it, I use [flags module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), i create a user flag for each  "run manualy my special rule" assigning flag/unflag access only to admin user and i display link on user profile page, flagging or unflagging myself to trigger my special rule, then, most of the time i use [views rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) to load content, products, orders or users and perform any kind of stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module. This is a way : [How to use](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7).

Comment: It is needed to run some other tasks than publishing and unpublishing content. Scheduler is only aimed for that feature, is that right?

Comment: Ok so you want to run scheduler for publishing & unpublishing content.

Comment: For example, a transmission of userpoints is scheduled, if it is needed to be clarified. I suppose, if a task can be executed manually, any task will be run in this way.